# VLOOKUP return column A text where column B has the largest number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have the following data in an Excel spreadsheet (just as example and not homework):

```
Item Name     Qty    Price
Apple           3    $3.00
Banana          5    $2.80
Orange          7    $1.20
```

I would like to know which item I have the most of. I have tried the following formula but it doesn't appear to be working:

> =VLOOKUP(MAX(B:B),A:C,1, FALSE)

My question is: a) am I using VLOOKUP correctly and b) is it the right function for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think VLOOKUP is not suitable because the Item is to the left of the Qty. Please try instead:

> =INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(B:B),B:B,0))

Your formula (with minor adaptation) would however be suitable to look up the Price associated with the maximum Qty (because Price is to the right of Qty):

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(B:B),B:C,2,FALSE)
```